# Can you avoid the shootout?

Tags: disco-elysium

Close to the climax of the *Disco Elysium* you have to participate in a showdown

> between the Hardy Boys and the mercenaries.

The latter ones accuse the former of lynching their comrade. While I've managed to mitigate the consequences a bit, it is still a bloodbath.

Is there a way to avoid it completely? I've read somewhere that arresting the main witness might change the conversation, but I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to avoid the shootout, although there are lots of ways to change the conversation.

It's not possible to arrest the main witness at that point since Ruby will either have died or run away, and you will not have encountered the Deserter at that point.

See [Fandom](https://discoelysium.fandom.com/wiki/Mercenary_Tribunal).

> - It's possible to save Titus Hardie, Elizabeth Beaufort, Shanky, Kim Kitsuragi.
> - It's impossible to save Glen, Fat Angus, Theo.